# Django - Bootstrap : modal

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have in a template 2 loop :

```
{% for person in players %}
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_personn"> {{person.user.username}} </a>
{% endfor %}

 {% for person in examiners %}
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_personn"> {{person.user.username}} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

And I have in the same template a modal :

```
<div id="modal_person" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <div>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"> {{person.user.username}} </h3> 
                    <i>{{ person.created_at|date:"d M, Y" }}</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% with subscribe = person.user.subscribe %}
                    {% if subscribe.age %}
                        <div>
                            {{subscribe.age }} years old
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if subscribe.presentation %}                                 
                        <h4> His presentation </h4>
                        <div class="row">
                            {{ subscribe.presentation }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"> Contact </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the problem is : I don't want to insert the modal in these two loops because at the end, they are many modals... and it's not proper.

So I want when a user click on the link in loops, this modal opens with data specific to current "person" of the loop.

How make this ?

I think to use this (data-id of modal) :

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_personn" data-id="{{person.user}}">{{person.user.username}} </a>
```

And the modal is completed with the value of data-id (Jquery). What do you think ?

**What is your solution for open a modal which contains value to current person in loop ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do exactly what you're asking is to use a library like jQuery to dynamically change the content of the modal depending on what link was clicked:

```
$("a.thumbnail").click(function() {
    var personId = $(this).attr('id');
    // Use jQuery to adjust the modal based on the data attributes.
    // You would still have to pass these attributes to the DOM
    // somehow, like
    var age = $(this).attr('age');
    $("#modal-person .age").text(age);
});
```

However, you say:

> So the problem is : I don't want to insert the modal in these two loops because at the end, they are many modals... and it's not proper.

It would be simpler to make a different modal for each person - there's nothing inherently improper about that. In fact, to implement the solution above, if you're not using AJAX every time someone clicks a modal button, you're going to have to pass all the data on each person into a data-attribute anyway. Why not just build all the various modals in a for loop if that's the case?

Code being DRY isn't about having less rendered HTML - if you're rendering the modals in a for loop it's still DRY code.

Comment: I'm afraid that at end my template contains 20 and more modals ! In fact, if my first loop contains 10 laps and the second also, my page will contain 20 modals because in each lap, a modal was build... (Moreover bootstrap-modal use javascrip, I think)

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is - you're going to have to pass all the data from the server anyway. I.e., `subscribe.age`, `subscribe.presentation`, all those variables need to be accessible somehow. You can either pass them into your link as `data-attributes` and then use jQuery, but it's much simpler to just render those modals as HTML.

Comment: So, have a template wich contains many modals not necessarily used is nothing inherently improper ? Because witch my solution (data-id in modal), the template contains only one modal and this modal is completed when a link of loop was clicked..

Comment: So what do you think ? ^^

Comment: Nothing inherently improper with that many modals. If you were talking about 1,000 modals my opinion might be different, but not necessarily - it would mainly depend if you were loading images. Even then I don't think it's an issue, since simply rendering the HTML will provide better user experience when the modal gets clicked than having to manipulate the DOM with javascript.

Comment: Ok thank's ! So I will placed the modal in loops and I tested ! At the beginning I was afraid that many modals could be a problem but with yours answers, not !

Comment: Hum, with a big big loop and I test the loading time of page and finally I calculate the size of this page ^^